# Justified or Natural text alignment before iOS 7 Warning

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsstring, text-alignment

I have an iOS App that is targeted to iOS 6 and above (I know, I know. But a disturbing number of our users are still on iPhones that have never been updated) and I'm seeing a warning when I compile my app:

> Justified or Natural text alignment before iOS 7.0

This is seen for each place I've chosen "natural" text alignment for a control in my xib files. This is confusing to me, because the docs clearly state that `NSTextAlignmentNatural` is "Available in iOS 6.0 and later."

[NSString Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/)

No warnings are presented when I set the alignment in the code, only from the xib.

Unfortunately, I am unable to test this myself because I don't have an iOS 6 device. Is this a warning that I just need to ignore, or could issues still arise in the older devices?

Answer (score 1):

I just made a test project and got the same result with a `UILabel` set to justified.  I repeated with a `UITextArea` and didn't get the error, so it seems to only relate to setting justified on UILabels.

I ran the same code on an iOS 6 device I have here and didn't get a crash, it just stayed left aligned, so you can probably ignore it, but it is very odd.

Perhaps you could try setting attributed text on the UILabels instead and see if the same thing happens.

Comment: FYI while this may work for `UILabel`, I can say for certain now that it will definitely CRASH on a `UITextField` in iOS 6. Released my app with Natural text alignment and it crashes before an iOS 6 user can even log in. Oops.

Answer (score -2):

UILabel set to Left-justif,like this
[setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sn39d.jpg)